# Is there a log to shows any connections going out? - Ubuntu 12

Tags: security

For example if someone is trying to SSH into another server or connect to another server from my Ubuntu server?

Is there a log file for this?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 12.04???

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not by default. You can use your firewall to create one. Assuming you are using `ufw`:

```
# ufw allow out log to any proto tcp port 22
```

Will log all outgoing connections to any server on tcp port 22. The location of the logfile should be `/var/log/ufw.log` but it might log it to `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/syslog` depending on rsyslog's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is use the following command to check that:

```
sudo journalctl -u ssh
```

In case the log is too long you can `pipe` that into `tail` or `head` depending on which part of the records you want to see:

```
sudo journalctl -u ssh | [tail | head]
```

Comment: I should've posted that this is Ubuntu 12. Is there something available that supports an OS that old?

Comment: I am not familiar with that version of Ubuntu but it should be in `/var/log` a quick search with `sudo grep -i -R -l ssh /var/log` should tell you which files have this information